# Construction of Free Module as Adjunction: Aluffi Proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

Whenever we construct free constructions, it seems that we just check the bijection property, and not naturality. For example, consider $U: Mod_R \rightarrow Set$, the forgetful functor on $R$-modules for commutative ring $R$. Then, what we **want** is a functor $F:Set \rightarrow Mod_R$, such that $Mod_R(FA,M) \cong Set(A,UM)$ for all $A \in Set, M \in Mod_r$, where this isomorphism is natural in $A$ and $M$.

However, in Aluffi, he only checks the bijection condition, rather than the naturality condition (see image below).

In this case, is there any purely categorical way to demonstrate naturality of the isomorphism he constructs, which from the diagram is $Mod_R(FA,M) \rightarrow Set(A,UM)$, $\phi \rightarrow \phi \circ j$? Or is the naturality achieved in some other way? Or does it just not matter?

[image]

Comment: Naturality is automatic. That is, you can show that a functor has a left adjoint iff it has that adjoint "pointwise," meaning iff the relevant free objects exist. This is a good exercise.

Comment: Naturality in A is automatic, but not naturality in M.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, if you have some bijection of sets $C(LX,A)\cong D(X,RA)$ then you can lift this to a genuine adjunction (i.e. it being natural in both $X$ and $A$) if you "just" have naturality in one of the variables... **by possibly changing the definition of $L$ or $R$ on morphisms**.

In the universal morphism construction of adjunctions where you only have one functor, say $L$, and you build up $R$ bit by bit, that's fine; you are given the objects $RA$, $A\in C$ and then there is a *unique* way to "promote" $R$ to a functor s.t. the bijections $C(LX,A)\cong D(X,RA)$ are fully natural if you have the data of the terminal morphisms $\epsilon:LRA\to A$.

However, if $L$ and $R$ are already given to you as functors then you really do need to check naturality (in both variables); this is *not* automatic. You can keep the definition of $L$ and possibility be forced to change the definition of $R$, or keep the definition of $R$ and possibly change the definition of $L$.

In the excerpt from Aluffi, the author is providing you with the *objects* $L$ and then it follows from existence of the nice universal morphisms $A\to F^R(A)$ that $L$ is uniquely promotable to a functor such that the adjunction morphism is natural in both variables.

What is the universal morphism thing really saying? Secretly it's saying $C(LX,A)\cong D(X,RA)$ naturally in $A$ (in the context where $R$ is the given functor and $L$ is the thing being constructed). By Yoneda's lemma, for fixed $X$, such natural isomorphisms are in direct correspondnece with arrows $j:X\to RLX$ that satisfy a niceness property, specifically that $(LX,j)$ is initial in the category of elements of $D(X,R(-))$. *So*, naturality in $A$ is secretly already being given to you! (when you have the nice functions $j:A\to F^R(A)$ satisfying ...)

This can be made concrete with the whole "for any module $B$ and any set function $A\to B$ there exists a unique $F^R(A)\to B$ such that..." thing. After all that, it follows $F^R$ has a unique structure as a functor $\mathsf{Set}\to\mathsf{RMod}$ such that your given choice of isomorphism is natural in both variables.